# How to change 'character set' in Java?

Tags: java, character

Most of Korean use Window OS. And Window's Korean character set is "EUC-KR". So when mac os x user use the file that is made by Window user, they have to use some website to change its character to unicode or have to use program that provide function which change character to unicode. Now I am making some program that use text-data-file on mac os x. So I want to provide my program the function which change character set to unicode. How to change 'EUC-KR' character to unicode 'UTF-8' in java?

Comment: I use `InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("iconv -f EUC-KR -t UTF-8 "+file.getPath()).getInputStream());` and It works properly.

Answer (score 0):

try commons-io function IOUtils.toString(InputStream, String)

```
public static String toString(InputStream input, String encoding)
```

the tool [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.15/iconv.1.html) also could help to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");

public static String getDefaultCharEncoding(){
        byte [] bArray = {'w'};
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bArray);
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
        String defaultCharacterEncoding = reader.getEncoding();
        return defaultCharacterEncoding;
    }
```

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/get-set-default-character-encoding.html#ixzz4gYeXFUxn